# Sort Range in Excel 365 Web Browser w/o VBA or Ribbon Controls

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

I currently only develop client-side spreadsheets. They are not normal sheets. A new workbook is created weekly, each day has 2 tabs. We recently changed from Google Sheets to Office 365. Everyone has an E1 license that I'm building for, I have an E3 license without Admin privileges. The behind the scenes differences between Sheets & Excel has caused some issues with rebuilding for a different platform.

My issue is I'm building spreadsheets for the semi tech-illiterate who need a button or dropdown trigger to run basic functions. I can't allow them to sort a range using the standard sort functions in the ribbon, as they will, and always, do it wrong, causing formulas to malfunction. I have everything fixed except for the sort button for each page.

With Sheets I used Scripts which ran great. With Excel, I can't use VBA/Macros because the typical user only has web browser access to Excel with their E1 license. Javascript in Excel is either not an option (I am trying to get IT to give me Office.js Automate Tab) or I'm to use Visual Basic which can build ridiculously powerful functions, but I can't figure out how to do a simple sort range function specific to one spreadsheet that will work when the sheet is copied and renamed without redeploying every week.

There has to be a simple solution to automate sorting the same cell range on the same pages in Excel like Google Script that will work in a browser version of Excel, with a simple trigger.

Anyone have any ideas, or have I already listed my options? It just seems so crazy that Excel can do so many things, but I can't find something as simple as "sort button for web".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to sort that range in place, another alternative would be to use a Pivot Table.

That Pivot Table would be referencing the range you want to sort (with the field in the Rows or Columns area depending on the orientation). And by having it sorted, the end user would simply have to right-click on the Pivot Table and select Refresh for the table to be updated with the sorted range.

[image]

Comment: It must sort in place, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your end to end scenario, but if you want to sort the range, you could use `range.sort` API. The document can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangesort?view=excel-js-preview

```
const header = range.find(criteria, {});
header.load("rowIndex");
await context.sync();

range.sort.apply(
  [
    {
      key: header.rowIndex,
      sortOn: Excel.SortOn.value
    }
  ],
  false /*matchCase*/,
  true /*hasHeaders*/,
  Excel.SortOrientation.columns
);
await context.sync();
```

We also have worksheet sort event. `Worksheet.onRowSorted`, it will trigger when the sorted is done. the document can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#onrowsorted

Here is the sample code:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    console.log("Adding row handler");
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    // This will fire whenever a row has been moved as the result of a sort action.
    sheet.onRowSorted.add((event) => {
        return Excel.run((context) => {
            console.log("Row sorted: " + event.address);
            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

            // Clear formatting for section, then highlight the sorted area.
            sheet.getRange("A1:E5").format.fill.clear();
            if (event.address !== "") {
                sheet.getRanges(event.address).format.fill.color = "yellow";
            }

            return context.sync();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would assume this is for building in Visual Studio? I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve every user installing an add-in. Also since there is a new sheet each week, wouldn't I need to make a new add-in for each sheet?